# Converting SAS syntax to lmer in R

Tags: r, spss, sas, lme4

Hi I am relatively new to running mixed models in R. But I have experience using them in SAS Proc Mixed and SPSS Mixed. I have the following code that I would like some help translating to use for lmer in R:

```
PROC MIXED COVTEST; 
CLASS ACTOR PARTNER DYAD GROUP; 
MODEL LEAD = /S DDFM=SATTERTH NOTEST; 
RANDOM INTERCEPT /TYPE=VC SUB=ACTOR; 
RANDOM INTERCEPT /TYPE=VC SUB=PARTNER; 
RANDOM INTERCEPT / TYPE=VC SUB=GROUP; 
REPEATED /TYPE=CS SUB=DYAD;
```

alternatively, the code in SPSS would be:

```
MIXED
LEAD BY GROUP
/FIXED =
/PRINT = SOLUTION TESTCOV
/RANDOM INTERCEPT | SUBJECT(GROUP) COVTYPE(VC) .
/RANDOM INTERCEPT | SUBJECT(ACTOR) COVTYPE(VC)
/RANDOM INTERCEPT | SUBJECT(PARTNER) COVTYPE(VC)
/RANDOM INTERCEPT | SUBJECT(DYAD) COVTYPE(VC) .
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is more on-topic at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), but I'll answer it anyway. It looks like you're trying to fit [Kenny's Social Relations Model](http://davidakenny.net/srm/srm.htm), which I have a little experience with.

The short answer is that this can't currently be done in lme4. The reason is that the SAS script involves "R-side covariance structures" (i.e., it invokes the `REPEATED` statement), but these are not currently supported in lme4. As an alternative, you might look into the [TripleR](http://www.persoc.net/Toolbox/TripleR) package to see if it fits your needs.

As a final comment, I don't think your SAS and SPSS models are equivalent. The SAS model (if I remember all the syntax correctly) uses a `REPEATED` statement to allow the residual variance to vary across dyads. But the SPSS model instead has random dyad effects (via a `RANDOM` statement), which I don't think is statistically equivalent. I'm not 100% sure though, as it is sometimes possible to get equivalent results using either `RANDOM` or `REPEATED` statements.

Comment: Yes I am trying to fit the SRM model. I like the Triple R program very much. But I am trying to find an all around solution because I also need to fit some half-block designs, where males rate females, and females rate males only. As you probably know Triple R does not do that. I thought about using SPSS or SAS per Kenny's instructions but both seem to take a really long time (4 - 5 hours). So I was wondering about fitting the mixed models in R. I don't know if it might be possible to fit the round robin designs in Triple R and fit the half block designs using lme4. Thanks for the help.